# Create an Object and set its instance variables using bufferedScanner

Tags: java, arrays, csv, bufferedreader

Im trying to read text from a csv file, use lineScanner to seperate out the values, and then create an object using the first token, and set the instance variables of the class to following tokens. Then I have to use these variables to calculate the teams total points using a method I have already created, and then store the Team object into the array referenced by teams.

All I have been able to do is seperate the csv file, but am unsure how to proceed from here.

Class Team

```
public class Team implements Comparable<Team>
{
   private String name;
   private int won; 
   private int drawn; 
   private int lost; 
   private int fourOrMoreTries; 
   private int sevenPointsOrLess; 
   private int totalPoints; 

   public Team(String aName)
   {
      super();
      this.name = aName;
```

Class Pool

```
public class Pool
{
   /* instance variables */
   private String poolName; // the name of the pool
   private Team[] teams;    // the teams in the pool
   private final static int NOOFTEAMS = 5; // number of teams in each pool

   /**
    * Constructor for objects of class Pool
    */
   public Pool(String aName)
   {
      super();
      this.poolName = aName;
      this.teams = new Team[NOOFTEAMS];

public void loadTeams()
   {
      String fileName;
      OUDialog.alert("Select input file for " + this.getPoolName());
      fileName = OUFileChooser.getFilename();
      File aFile = new File(fileName);
      Scanner bufferedScanner = null;

      try
      {
         String teamName;
         int teamWon;
         int teamDrawn;
         int teamLost;
         int teamFourOrMoreTries;
         int teamSevenPointsOrLess;
         Scanner lineScanner;
         String currentLine;
         bufferedScanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(aFile)));
         currentLine = bufferedScanner.nextLine();

         if (!poolName.equals(currentLine))
         {
           OUDialog.alert("Wrong File Selected");           
         }
         else
         {
            while (bufferedScanner.hasNextLine())
         {
               currentLine = bufferedScanner.nextLine();
               lineScanner = new Scanner(currentLine);            
               lineScanner.useDelimiter(",");
               teamName = lineScanner.next();
               teamWon = lineScanner.nextInt();
               teamDrawn = lineScanner.nextInt();
               teamLost = lineScanner.nextInt();
               teamFourOrMoreTries = lineScanner.nextInt();
               teamSevenPointsOrLess = lineScanner.nextInt();                                               
             }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I have a few things to say in regards to the code you have posted.

1) The team class in incomplete. If you want you should make you constructor take more parameters so what you can create an instance of Team without getters/setters.

For example:

```
public Team(String aName, int... ints) {
  this.won = ints[0];
  this.name = aName;
  this.drawn = ints[1]; 
 // and so on....
}
```

Then create a List of teams in you pools class,

```
List<Team> listofTeams = new ArrayList<Team>();
```

at the end of you while:

```
while (bufferedScanner.hasNextLine())
     {
           currentLine = bufferedScanner.nextLine();
           lineScanner = new Scanner(currentLine);            
           lineScanner.useDelimiter(",");
           teamName = lineScanner.next();
           teamWon = lineScanner.nextInt();
           teamDrawn = lineScanner.nextInt();
           teamLost = lineScanner.nextInt();
           teamFourOrMoreTries = lineScanner.nextInt();
           teamSevenPointsOrLess = lineScanner.nextInt();                                               
         }
       listofTeams.add(new Team(teamName, teamWon, teamDrawn, ... add more ints);
```

2) Do you know what super(); does? you are right it's needed but not if the super is Object and not if the super takes no parameters. It is assume you called super() no parameters as first statement in constructor if it isnt there. So you really don't need the call to the super... your super class is Object in your classes

There are many more things you need to work on. Does your school have office hours? if they do perhaps they can help you out.